# Avoid downcasting in an inherited tree class

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++ and I'm right now facing a point in my design where I cannot seem to avoid downcasting. I know this is usually a sign of bad design, so I would like to know what would be a better way to do this.

I have a class `Frame` that represents geometrical frame trees and allows geometrical transformations between them:

```
class Frame
{
    private:
      Frame *_parent;
      std::vector<Frame*> _children;

    public:
      Frame* getParent() const;
      std::vector<Frame*> getChildren() const;
      ... (extra methods for geometrical transformations)
}
```

I want now to create a new `Frame` subclass, `MechanicalFrame`, that adds some functionality to deal with dynamical properties.

```
class MechanicalFrame
{
   private:
     double mass;
     ...
   public:
     void compute();
 }
```

My problem is that, the "compute" method needs to implement some recursive logic, so it would contain something like this:

```
MechanicalFrame::compute()
{
   for element in getChildren():
     element.compute();
}
```

However, since `getChildren` returns a `vector` of `Frame*` and not `MechanicalFrame*`, I would need to make a `static_cast` at this point. I've given the problem a lot of thought, but none of the solutions I've found are fully satisfying to me:

Solution 1) Static cast: somehow it indicates bad design

Solution 2) Add the compute method to the base class (`Frame`) with a dummy implementation, i.e., throwing an exception: it seems unnatural to force the implementation of the parent class based on the derived class.

Solution 3) Split totally `MechanicalFrame` from `Frame`: this would mean reimplementing many of the functionalities already available in `Frame`.

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Create `Frame::compute()` in base class and make it `virtual`. The question is - are you going to instantiate base class ? Maybe making `Frame` an abstract class would be a good idea.

Comment: If you are sure that all the `Frame*` pointers in `MechanicalFrame::getChildren()` are pointing to `MechanicalFrame` instances, I don't see any problem with `static_cast`. Make sure you use `dynamic_cast` + `assert` in **debug builds** to catch mistakes

Comment: @VittorioRomeo it's really ugly design.

Comment: I think a `static_cast` is prettier than leaking derived class details into the parent class.

Comment: @pSoLT: fair, but the developer "statically knows" the real type of all these pointers. I would use `static_cast` because we have "static knowledge" and we can avoid virtual dispatch here

Comment: First of all, make `_children` protected if you want to use it in derived class.

Comment: @pSoLT Disagree, it's better to use `addChild`/`getChildren` methods in derived classes

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 you are right, I didn't notice that he used `getChildren` method ( which still should return `std::vector<Frame*>&` by the way )

Comment: How are children added to a `MechanicalFrame`? How is it enforced that they are also `MechanicalFrame`?

Comment: @ChrisDrew Children are only added to the parent nodes at construction of the children. Nothing but the user prevents from having a Frame as a child of a MechanicalFrame.

Answer (score 3):

Use polymorphic behaviour, use your Solution 2)

You can follow below pattern (Interface -> Base class -> Derived class)

```
class IFrame
{
public:
    virtual void compute()=0;
}

class Frame:public IFrame
{
public:
    virtual void compute() {/*nothing to do*/}
}

class MechanicalFrame:public Frame
{
public:
    virtual void compute() {/*your implementation with mass*/}
}
```

Comment: That's what i've written in comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that all the `Frame*` pointers in `MechanicalFrame::getChildren()` are pointing to `MechanicalFrame` instances, I don't see any problem with `static_cast`. Make sure you use `dynamic_cast` + `assert` in **debug builds** to catch mistakes.

```
void MechanicalFrame::compute()
{
    for(auto frame_ptr : getChildren())
    {
        downcast<MechanicalFrame*>(frame_ptr)->compute();
    }
}
```

Where `downcast` is something like:

```
template <typename TOut, typename T>
auto downcast(T* ptr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, TOut>{});

    assert(ptr != nullptr);
    assert(dynamic_cast<TOut>(ptr) == ptr);

    return static_cast<TOut>(ptr);
}
```

*(For a more thorough implementation of `downcast` see my [Meeting C++ 2015 lightning talk **"Meaningful casts"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62c_Xm6Zh1k) or my [current implementation in `vrm_core`](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_core/blob/master/include/vrm/core/casts/polymorphic.hpp).)*

---

Notice that there's a performance advantage here, as you avoid `virtual` dispatch. Play around with [this snippet on gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/GMLUbj) to see differences in the generated assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Visitor pattern:

```
class Frame;
class MechanicalFrame;

class FrameVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~FrameVisitor() = default;

    virtual void visit(Frame&) = 0;

    virtual void visit(MechanicalFrame&) = 0;
};

class Frame
{
public:
    virtual void accept(FrameVisitor& visitor)
    {
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }

    void acceptRecursive(FrameVisitor& visitor)
    {
        accept(visitor);

        for (Frame* child : getChildren())
        {
            child->acceptRecursive(visitor);
        }
    }

    ...
};

class MechanicalFrame : public Frame
{
public:
    virtual void accept(FrameVisitor& visitor) override
    {
        visitor.visit(*this);
    }

    ...
};
```

Then the client code will be:

```
class ConcreteVisitor : public FrameVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Frame& frame) override
    {
        // Deal with Frame (not a subclass) object.
    }

    virtual void visit(MechanicalFrame& frame) override
    {
        // Deal with MechanicalFrame object.
    }
};

Frame root = ...;
ConcreteVisitor visitor;
root.acceptRecursive(visitor);
```

In general, the Visitor pattern allows you to traverse a hierarchy of heterogeneous objects and perform operations on them without type casting. It's most useful when the number of operations is expected to grow while your type hierarchy is more or less stable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for new ideas, I will not explain in detail anything you written about in solutions 1-3.

You could add extra functionality to the `MechanicalFrame` class, splitting its `children` of `MechanicalFrame` class and all other classes, like this:

```
class Frame {
public:
    std::vector<Frame*> getChildren(); // returns children
    void addChild(Frame* child);       // adds child to children
private:
    std::vector<Frame*> children;
}

class MechanicalFrame : public Frame {
public:
    void compute();
    std::vector<MechanicalFrame*> getMechanicalChildren(); // returns mechanical_children
    void addChild(MechanicalFrame* child);                 // adds child to mechanical_children
private:
    std::vector<MechanicalFrame*> mechanical_children;
}
```

One possible implementation of `compute` is the following:

```
void MechanicalFrame::compute() {
    ...
    for (auto* child : getMechanicalChildren()) {
        child->compute();
    }
}
```

**UP:** As far as I understand, one of the problems with casts is that the code starts behaving very differently depending on the actual class of the object, and we cannot substitute the parent class object with child class (see [Liskov principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). The approach described in this answer actually changes the principle of using the "mechanicity" of your `Frame`s, allowing adding `MechanicalFrame` children in such a way that they're ignored in `compute` method.